# Reading UTF-8 strings from a binary file

Tags: python, utf-8

I have some files which contains a bunch of different kinds of binary data and I'm writing a module to deal with these files.

Amongst other, it contains UTF-8 encoded strings in the following format: 2 bytes big endian *stringLength* (which I parse using struct.unpack()) and then the string. Since it's UTF-8, the length in bytes of the string may be greater than *stringLength* and doing read(stringLength) will come up short if the string contains multi-byte characters (not to mention messing up all the other data in the file).

How do I read *n* UTF-8 characters (distinct from *n* bytes) from a file, being aware of the multi-byte properties of UTF-8? I've been googling for half an hour and all the results I've found are either not relevant or makes assumptions that I cannot make.

Comment: Are you certain that stringLength is characters and not bytes?

Comment: wow, that'd be a really *terrible* format. Do you have the data already read into a string or list of some sort? UTF-8 bytes can be inspected easily enough to determine how many bytes follow to make a character, but you need to process these character-by-decoded-character.

Comment: @GrahamBorland 100%? No, I have yet to find a file that actually uses multibyte characters, but it is my interpretation of the specification that this is the case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay, how do I do that in Python? Is there a convenient module I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a file object, and a number of characters, you can use:

```
# build a table mapping lead byte to expected follow-byte count
# bytes 00-BF have 0 follow bytes, F5-FF is not legal UTF8
# C0-DF: 1, E0-EF: 2 and F0-F4: 3 follow bytes.
# leave F5-FF set to 0 to minimize reading broken data.
_lead_byte_to_count = []
for i in range(256):
    _lead_byte_to_count.append(
        1 + (i >= 0xe0) + (i >= 0xf0) if 0xbf < i < 0xf5 else 0)

def readUTF8(f, count):
    """Read `count` UTF-8 bytes from file `f`, return as unicode"""
    # Assumes UTF-8 data is valid; leaves it up to the `.decode()` call to validate
    res = []
    while count:
        count -= 1
        lead = f.read(1)
        res.append(lead)
        readcount = _lead_byte_to_count[ord(lead)]
        if readcount:
            res.append(f.read(readcount))
    return (''.join(res)).decode('utf8')
```

Result of a test:

```
>>> test = StringIO(u'This is a test containing Unicode data: \ua000'.encode('utf8'))
>>> readUTF8(test, 41)
u'This is a test containing Unicode data: \ua000'
```

In Python 3, it is of course *much, much easier* to just wrap the file object in a [`io.TextIOWrapper()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) and leave decoding to the native and efficient Python UTF-8 implementation.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I'm looking for. Accepted and upvoted. Is it enough that I link to your StackOverflow profile when attributing that section to you?

Comment: @Surma: Sure; all content of this site is licensed as CC-wiki (see bottom right) but the readcount 'function' was adapted from a [simple C macro](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/utf8_8h_source.html), so I was reusing stuff too. :-) All in all, this is simple stuff once you understand the underlying byte formats.

Comment: @Surma: There are also more pythonic ways to determine the `readcount` value; they may even be faster than what I used here. This one uses between 2 and 4 (simple) tests per byte.

Comment: @Surma: Updated: moved to using a table instead, so that your inner loop only has to do one lookup per lead byte.

Comment: Are you sure that mapping is correct from 248 and up? `248` is `11111000` i.e the `start byte of 3-byte sequence`, but is mapped to `4`

Comment: @root: no, 248 is the start of a 5-byte sequence. See the [UTF-8 descriptions on WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). The number of `1` bits before the first `0` bit (read from the left) is the total number of bytes in a sequence.

Comment: wasn't `uft-8` [restricted to 4 bytes from 2003 onwards](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629.txt) and the WP table is as originally proposed?

Comment: @root: Sure, but this code is isn't trying to validate anything either, and in practice you'll never find any codepoints using 5 or 6 bytes. You could alter the table generator to insert 0s for anything over 240 instead. That doesn't make `3` the correct answer for the `248` byte though. :-P In that case the last part of that test becomes `if i < 0xf0 else 0`.

Comment: @root: But *if* there is UTF-8 data out there that does use 5 or 6 bytes, there is no point in breaking things here.

Comment: @root: Some experimenting shows the Python UTF-8 decoder refuses anything with 5 or 6 bytes anyway (it rejects a starting byte over 0xf4 out of hand) so I'll adjust.

Comment: I read the unicode standard couple of days ago, thinking that I have got it covered now, it seems not to be so straight forward :) Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @root: NP. Adjusted now, there is no point in handling bytes over 0xF4 since the Python UTF-8 codec won't decode those anyway. This way at least it won't read more data from the obviously broken data stream.

Comment: @root: There, some more shaving and it is getting to be a lot more pythonic. :-P

Comment: For python 3 change (''.join(res)).decode('utf8') to (b''.join(res)).decode('utf8')

Comment: @Sovetnikov: just use `bytes(res).decode()`. Or, don't handle raw UTF-8 bytes yourself and use the standard library `io.TextIOWrapper()` object.

Answer (score 0):

One character in UTF-8 can be 1byte,2bytes,3byte3.

If you have to read your file byte by byte, you have to follow the UTF-8 encoding rules.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Most the time, you can just set the encoding to utf-8, and read the input stream.

You do not need to care how much bytes you have read.

Comment: I googled setting input stream encoding and got the docs on the `codecs` module. If I understand this correctly, I could do something like this:
`strLen = struct.unpack('>h', f.read(2))
utfStream = codecs.open(f, 'r', 'utf-8')
string = utfStream.read(strLen)`
One question though: Will this advance the pointer in my file descriptor, so that subsequent `read()`'s on `f` will return bytes *after* the string I just read?
Edit: Where did the newlines in my code example go?